# How to bind a DataGrid to a datatable from database using MVVM in wpf?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

My model, viewmodel and XAML is as follows:

**This is my ViewModelClass:**

```
class AllResultsViewModel
{

    private ICommand _clickCommand;
    public ICommand ClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _clickCommand ?? (_clickCommand = new CommandHandler(param => this.MyAction(_cvm),
                param => this._canExecute));
        }
    }
    private bool _canExecute;
    private ComboBoxViewModel _cvm;
    public DataTable AllResults { get; set; }
    public AllResultsViewModel(ComboBoxViewModel CVM)
    {
        _canExecute = true;
        _cvm = CVM;
    }

    public void MyAction(ComboBoxViewModel cvm)
    {
       //Connecting to DB to retrieve data in datatable
    }
}
public class CommandHandler : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _execute;
    // private bool _canExecute;
    private Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    public CommandHandler(Action<object> execute)
    : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
    public CommandHandler(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #endregion // Constructors

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameters)
    {
        //  return _canExecute;
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameters);
    }

    //  public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameters)
    {
        _execute(parameters);
    }

}
```

**My XAML is as follows:**

```
                <DataGrid Name="results_grid" IsReadOnly="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding AllResults}" DisplayMemberPath="AllResultsGrid" ColumnWidth="100" RowHeight="30">
```

**My Model Class:**

public class AllResultsModel
    {
        private DataTable _allresultsgrid;

```
    public DataTable AllResultsGrid
    {
        get { return _allresultsgrid; }
        set { _allresultsgrid = value; }
    }

}
```

Am I missing anything here? The code is getting built successfully and the data is retrieved from DB. But I m not able to view it in Datagrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like you are missing the propertychanged() call.
I am pretty sure that the data table does not fire any property changed events.
try calling propertychanged on the "AllResults" property once you finished loading the data to it.

Comment: Thanks. Under MyAction(), I added PropertyChanged("AllResults") and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very confused and I think you need to learn well how to use MVVM : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/ (download the PDF).

In your Model.cs you need to define only your classes that defines your objects like below:

```
public class MyData
{
  public int Par1{ get; set; }
  public string Par2 { get; set; }
  public string Par3 { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to create an observable collection in your ViewModel implementing NotifiyPropertyChanged:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MyData> myData = ObservableCollection<MyData>;
    public ObservableCollection<MyData>  MyData
    {
        get { return myData; }
        set { myData = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("MyData"); }
    }
}
```

Then in the ViewModel you will execute the MyAction() function like this:

```
public void MyAction(ComboBoxViewModel cvm)
{
   //Connecting to DB to retrieve data in datatable
   MyData = new ObservableCollection<MyData>(dataFromDB);
}
```

Finally you simply binding MyData in the ItemsSource in the xaml.

> Remember to assign your viewmodel like page/windows datacontext!